# How to get this font from Apple Page?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to use the same font from Apple presentation in my own HTML. I've tried using console to determine the font, but apparently is not the correct one.

https://help.apple.com/osx-mavericks/whats-new-from-lion

this CSS is not good, even if it's the same on Apple page.

```
{ font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;}
```

[image]

this is my version
[image]

Any ideas how they do it?

Answer (score 0):

They are doing something a little tricky. They are using a background image with the anti-aliased text saved as a png. Then using `color: transparent` on `figure h1, figure h2` to hide the actual rendered HTML text. That allows them to control the exact experience from a graphic editor, but allows the page to be crawled by a search engine, or if someone wants a text only version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Its an image and the text they have made font color transparent[image]. No rocket science about it. color: transparent

Answer (score 0):

The CSS you posted is only a small part of it and they may not be even using it. Check out: https://help.apple.com/osx-mavericks/en.lproj/img/S0010_iBooks/S0018_Header.png